# Sonar INVALID HASH

Tags: sonarqube

After upgrading to 3.5.1, our Sonar shows INVALID HASH error in one of our slave machine (we have 1 master and 3 slaves). I found all file size under C:\Users\xxxxx.sonar\cache_tmp is zero. But other directories like C:\Users\xxxxx.sonar\cache\1b8de6f094e072c092b4ef1b332fdbf0 still has file (like commons-dbcp-1.3.jar) and the file is correct.

This is the error message, is there any suggestion for it?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXXX: Can not execute Sonar: INVALID HASH: File C:\Users\xxxxx\.sonar\cache\_tmp\1374226573512-28 was expected to have hash 099c91d9bb47f3c7f98b0e1825f593df but was downloaded with hash d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -> [Help 1]
17:36:11 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXXX: Can not execute Sonar
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
17:36:11    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
17:36:11    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:36:11    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
17:36:11    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
17:36:11    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
17:36:11    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
17:36:11    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
17:36:11    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
17:36:11    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

And it still doesn't work after adding 'SONAR_USER_HOME' environment variable 
(http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-INVALIDHASH)

Answer (score 0):

you should try to delete the local cache. A file has been corrupted during download. The FAQ is going to be updated. 
Thanks

Comment: We clean the cache but it doesn't work. Finally we copy all cache files from master's cache directory to slave's directory and it's ok now. But when we have new plugin (or new version), I need to do it again.

Comment: Indeed this not an acceptable workaround for read production use. You should check the HTTP connection between your box and the server and understand why files are corrupted. For example is there a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,

***Solution*** there was space problem in user home directory, so I created a soft link .sonar in user home directory to tmp directory and it worked or you can pass sonar.userHome=/usr/tmp to get it working.

Issue while running sonar Qube on Jenkins

```
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.7.0_75 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project configuration file: /usr/local/build/jenkins_home/head_fast_gradle/workbench/build/tmp/sonarRunner/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "US-ASCII" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /usr/local/build/jenkins_home/head_fast_gradle/workbench/build/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.4
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.487s
Final Memory: 3M/481M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Fail to download libraries from server
ERROR: Caused by: INVALID HASH: File /fmac/users/bldmgr/.sonar/cache/_tmp/1432846057632-440 was expected to have hash 60dd4c0ee91e594a20faa75f80182956 but was downloaded with hash d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
:sonarRunner FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

When I inspected this url, http://mysonar:9000/sonar/api/plugins/installed, the hash of one plugin was uncorrect. 
I restarted the sonar server and the hash value at this url was updated with the correct value.

Note that the jar of the plugin was not modified on the server. In my case the corruption was not in the cache but in the server itself.

I use sonar version 6.7.